# ASP Button only clickable on text and border

Tags: asp.net, ajax

We are having an issue with all of our ASP buttons.  One of the last steps that we took before going live with a new version of our application was replacing 100's of image buttons with asp:buttons that were styled to have a gradient since that was all the images were as well with different text on them.
  **`The problem is that we can only click on the button text or the border of the button.  The rest of the button area is not clickable at all.  I strongly suspect that this is related to the fact that we are now using the ajax toolkit, but I can not prove it.  All of our buttons have this issue now including non image buttons that were working perfectly before.`** 
 I have individually replaced all of the css and that has not made a difference at all.  Also the closest I can find to similar type questions mentions working with display:block.  None of that works at all and doing something like an href or wrapping divs is not an option.  This is literally hundreds of buttons and recreating them will not work.  The only other option I see left is the ajax toolkit.  I can not post code or even create psuedo code or smaller projects that are similar to the actual code.  I can say that we are designing for IE 9 and I am suspicious that in IE 10 and all other browsers we would probably not have this issue, but since IE 9 is mandated we must find a way to work around this.  I realize it is tough without code, but if you can just point me in the right direction of the error I am sure I can figure it out.

Thanks
Jimmy

Comment: Looks like something related to CSS padding and margin... without code it's difficult to tell really...

Answer (score 0):

This is a css issue, you can inspect the button using chrome or firefox (i prefer chrome) and see what css properties your button has, then disable those properties (on fly) one by one clicking on their checkbox and see if your button is clickable after disabling a property.